# How to use helper typography functions in gatsby part 3 tutorial

Tags: gatsby

In part 3 of Gatsby tutorial in Using Gatsby Plugin section we are exporting some helper functions.

```
export const { scale, rhythm, options } = typography
```

How I can actually use those functions to change anything? Simply importing and invoking on page (tested on about-css-modules.js) brings no changes in displayed text.

```
import { scale } from "../utils/typography"
scale(2/5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the typography package is to define your typographic styles in a seperate file such as `src/utils/typography.js` and then use these styles throughout your project.

If you want to override a theme, as in use the helper typography functions, you need to use override ThemeStyles. This is described on their [github page](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typography.js/#customizing-themes).

The example from the github README:

```
import Typography from 'typography'
import funstonTheme from 'typography-theme-funston'
funstonTheme.overrideThemeStyles = ({ rhythm }, options) => ({
  'h2,h3': {
    marginBottom: rhythm(1/2),
    marginTop: rhythm(2),
  }
})

const typography = new Typography(funstonTheme)
```

One tip: If you want to learn Gatsby, **skip understanding the typography.js package**. The point of the tutorial part 3 is to show you how you can use Gatsby plugins to help you develop faster. The typography.js package helps you with styling your text. There are thousands of other Gatsby plugins that help you with other stuff. typography.js is just an example. Maybe you don't care much about that yet so just skip this package and use default browser typography or plain old CSS classes.